# Long term effects of sitting on chair with leg rest on back health?

Tags: back, posture

I am wondering if there is any scientific data or medical knowledge about the long-term effects of sitting on a chair with a leg rest on back health.

In particular, consider an individual who works long hours at a desk job. If they spend most of their time with their legs on a leg rest, will that have any known effect on their back health in the long term?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.